# removing duplicate <strong> tags in HTML Collection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have paragraph and some of the words are displayed using `<strong>` tag.
For instance, this text include `<strong>MyWord</strong>` which I intend to use for learning vocabulary.  There's also `<strong>another word</strong>` highlighted. This paragraph consists of tens of strong words.

I am aiming to obtain an HTMLCollection of unique strong words.

Initially when I use `getElementsByTagName("strong").length`, It contains duplicate strong words and the actualy length of unique words is not correct.
How can I remove HTMLCollections or uniquely identify collection of strong words?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the number of each unique strong word?

Comment: but I also want list of unique strong words

Comment: Most answers assume you just want the textContent while in your question you said you wanted an HTMLCollection (and thus elements). What do you plan to do with that collection of elements? Is the list of unique texts actually enough?

Answer (score 2):

After you get the list of words (by getting the texts from the `<strong>` elements), you can [remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/5459839) by running it through a Set constructor:

```js
let words = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("strong"), 
    el => el.textContent.trim()
);
words = [...new Set(words)]; // This removes duplicates
console.log(words.length); // 2
```

```html
There is <strong>MyWord</strong> which I intend to use for learning 
vocabulary. There's also <strong>another word</strong>, but then again
<strong>MyWord</strong>, which is duplicate and should not be counted.
```

Comment: OP asked for an HTMLCollection though.

Comment: @Kaiido most likely because tutorials still teach older techniques instead of using the easier modern solutions. I doubt that the actual question is to use `HTML Collection Objects` but how to count the amount of different strong words.

Comment: @tacoshy How is using an HTMLCollection any older than getting the textContent? And how do they relate anyway? They just don't do the same thing. And assuming they only want the number of unique words is a very strong assumption when they explicitly state that they want an HTMLCollection.

Comment: if you read the bottom part he is using `.length` and tries to read out the `the actual length of unique words`. HTMLCollection here is pointed towards the usage of `getElementsByClassName`. For the actual task of getting the length the modern solution of using a Node List is definitely easier (and more modern).

Comment: @tacoshy But the distinction is not in NodeList vs HTMLCollection which nowadays are just about the same, the distinction is between returning a list of Element objects versus returning a list of strings. I read the end of the question as being an explanation of what went wrong during their attempt at "obtain[ing] an HTMLCollection of unique strong words." They don't ask for just the length.

Comment: The asker asks for *"n HTMLCollection of unique strong words"*: if we interpret that as *"...unique strings"*, then it makes no sense, since an HTMLCollection is a collection of HTML elements. If they mean unique HTML Elements, then they already got that (since that is not dependent on the element's contents). So we need to re-interpret the question. That's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) like this:

```js
const output = document.querySelector('#output')
  const dedupeStrongWords = () => {
    const strongElements = document.querySelectorAll('strong');
    const strongWords = new Set();
    for (const e of strongElements) {
      strongWords.add(e.innerText.toLowerCase().trim());
    }
    output.innerText = Array.from(strongWords).join(', ')
  };
  dedupeStrongWords();
```

```html
<p>
  This is a <strong>paragraph</strong> where some words are marked as <strong>strong</strong>.
  <strong>Strong</strong> words should be <strong>deduped</strong> somehow.
  The easiest way is using <strong>sets</strong>.
</p>
<div>
  Deduped strong words: <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example:

```js
let div=document.getElementById("container");
let strongTagList = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
let counts = {};
let resultCollection=[];
for (let strongTag of strongTagList) {
  if (counts[strongTag.textContent]) {
    counts[strongTag.textContent]++;
  } else {
    counts[strongTag.textContent] = 1;
    resultCollection.push(strongTag);
  }
}
console.log(counts);
div.innerHTML="";
resultCollection.forEach(tag=>{
  div.append(tag);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <strong>2</strong>
  <strong>3</strong>
  <strong>3</strong>
  <strong>1</strong>
  <strong>1</strong>
  <strong>1</strong>
</div>
```